# Bash - How are '\' and newline characters interpreted within single quotes?

Tags: bash

According to the GNU documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) all text within single quotes should be interpreted literally.  I then tried creating two aliases:

```
alias alias1='
    echo hello'

alias alias2='\
    echo hello'
```

Executing `alias1` prints `hello`, as I expect.  Executing `alias2` results in no text being printed.  Going into a terminal and manually entering `\`, enter,     `echo hello` also prints `hello`.  Shouldn't `alias2` be identical to my manual test case?

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  In which version of bash are you seeing it fail?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with bash 5, which version do you have?

Comment: I can duplicate with `bash` 3.2. This is likely a problem with the `alias` built-in itself, not the quoted argument. The former should include a literal newline in the definition; the latter should not.

Comment: More precisely, it's repeatable in `bash` 4.1, but not `bash` 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to a bug fix in `bash` 4.2. From the change log:

> This document details the changes between this version,
> bash-4.2-alpha, and the previous version, bash-4.1-release.
>
> 1. Changes to Bash
>
>    a.  Fixed a bug in the parser when processing alias expansions
>    containing
>    quoted newlines.

As far as the definitions go, `alias1` should start with a newline, followed by several spaces, then the text `echo hello`. `alias2` should be nearly identical, with the exception that it does not begin with a newline. Either way, the whitespace preceding `echo` is discarded after the alias expansion, during parsing.

Comment: I just tested on a separate machine running 4.4, and both alias1 and alias2 work on there.  It does indeed seem to be an issue with bash that has since been fixed.  Thank you!